# Check my work on the the following theorem is correct

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, peano-axioms

Prove that if $m \leqslant n$ then $\exists!\ p\in\omega$. such that $m+p=n$

Correction:induction on $n$ thanks to @Brian M. Scott

Working assumptions:

**6.1 Definition** By the set of the natural numbers we mean the intersection of all the successor sets. The set of the natural numbers is designated by the symbol $\omega$; every element of $\omega$ is called a natural number.

$\omega$={0,1,2,3,…,n,…:n$\in$ $Z^{+}$ }

**$6.22$ Theorem**

Let $m \leqslant  n$ denote the fact that $m \in n$ or $m = n$. Then the relation   is an order relation in $\omega$.

**$6.13$ Theorem**

$(m+n)+k=m+(n+k)$.

**$6.11$ Lemma**

$n+ =1+n$, where $1$ is defined to be $0+$

Attempted proof

Let $m,n \in\omega $ be arbitrary.

Define $L_{pn} = \{m\in\omega : \text{ If } m\leqslant n \text{ then }\exists!\ p \text{ such that } n+p=m \}$

**Base case:**
$m=0, p=n$ so $0 \in L_{pn}$

**Inductive case**:

Assume $m\in L_{pn}$ We will show $m+\in L_{np}$

If $m \leqslant n$  then $m=n$ or $m \in n$
If $m=n$ we are done. Otherwise if $m \in n$ ;
$m \subset n$ so that $n= m^{+} +p$

Then $$\begin{align} 
n &= m^{+} +p\\
&= (m+p)+ \qquad\text{     Ind.hyp.}\\
&= 1+(m+p) \qquad\text{by 6.11}\\
&= (m+1)+p \qquad\text{by 6.13}\\
&= p+(m+)\qquad\quad\text{by 6.11}\end{align}$$
Thus $m+ \in L_{pn}$

It seems to me some of my proof deals with this post

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3796851/837396

Help

Comment: You should clearly define what is $\omega$.

Comment: Ok,I did that. See main post

Comment: Wow. The set of natural numbers is more commonly denoted by $\mathbb{N}$. One more thing, add the "elementary number theory" tag. I cannot solve your problem because I don't know number theory.

Comment: Problem deals with Peano’s arithmetic. The text I work from is A Book of Set theory by Charles Pinter . I have the PDF version which has typos

Comment: @Victor: This problem is actually more set-theoretic than anything else, and $\omega$ is standard in that context.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was not aware of that. Wow. At least in Analysis it is denoted by $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Eudoxus: I’m afraid that your argument in the induction step makes no sense. Part of the problem is that you got off on the wrong foot: for each $m\in\omega$ the induction should be on $n$. Note that you have to prove not only that $p$ exists, but that it’s unique.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ok So if I show the induction on is correct that proves p existence. ?Do I use induction to show uniqueness?

Comment: @Eudoxus: Yes, uniqueness can be shown by induction. But I’d concentrate first on proving existence.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Does induction on n prove p’s existence

Comment: @Eudoxus: Yes: as I said, for each $m$ you do an induction on $n$.

Comment: I fixed up your formatting problem. You can see how it is done by checking the edit (though arrays are a better way of handling the offset step explanations than I used). You can find out more on Latex via Mathjax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Need help with checking this proof." says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: The definition of $L_{np}$ is an incorrect statement, you should swap the  $n$ and the $m$ around to make it true

Comment: Ok ,l did it @JoshuaPasa